# Advice or insult?

Tags: discussion

Question goes to all as follows:

If a person asks a question seeking for advice, how is he handled by higher reputation people?

If advice is asked for by a student on Stack Overflow it should not be tagged as homework, but indeed be answered as an abstract.

The guy will obviously approach the seniors to ask how to do a particular thing, rather then braking his head thinking on his own.

If at all the guy has put a question straight from the assignment then it should be tagged as homework, where he would expect a ready made answer!

Insulting the student brings his morale down, from using this sites further on...
It is an utter insult to the seniors to see that no work is done by the person before asking a question but I guess the seniors can ignore that if they think it is insult for them, or rather put a warm comment appealing that the answer wont be posted if the person asking the question doesn't want to work only on it.

So, what are seniors thoughts about this? Are we here to share knowledge or insult the new-bees?

Comment: Where is the example? Without the example this question can only be answered in an extremely general way.

Comment: @slugster: Probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512381/time-table-generation-using-genetic-algorithms-in-java

Comment: Just to let you know, [downvotes work slightly differently here on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @shridatt, is there any reason why you have a *zero%* **SO** accept rate? ~on some of the answers you have received, you have even commented on with the likes of: `thanks [...] simple and clean. Great work :) :)` ~so what's going on?

Comment: @violet313 i need to get to basics...even i feel that now!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't generally give "advice", since "advice" is subjective and answers may vary widely.

First and foremost, this is not an educational institution. You seem to be comparing us to one, with all the "seniors" you refer to.

> The guy will obviously approach the seniors to know how to do a particular thing, rather then braking his head thinking on his own.

Look, we are not going to help you for any little problem there is. Despite being a Q&A site, our primary goal is to *make the Internet better*. "Good questions" involve those which will be asked by others, among other things. "Good answers" should help *other* visitors learn.

There are *too many* quick-fix forums where any little problem is handed an answer. They aren't really useful, in my opinion--too much noise. The fact that we try to make the Internet better separates us from the rest.

> If at all the guy has put a question straight from the assignment then it should be tagged as homework , where he would expect a ready made answer!

The homework tag isn't just for homework, it is for homework-like questions. And we won't just give ready made answers as stated above, unless the question is good.

> Insulting the student brings his moral down, from using this sites further on... It is utter insult to the seniors to see that no work is done by the person before asking a question but i guess the seniors can ignore that if they think it is insult for them, or rather put a warm comment appealing that the answer wont be posted if the person asking the question doesn't want to work only on it.

I sort of don't see what you're trying to say here. We're not insulting anyone on purpose. If your question was closed/downvoted, it usually means that it doesn't follow our guidelines. Most of them are summarized in our [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq); read it first.

> So, what are seniors thoughts about this? are we here to share knowledge or insult the new-bees?

We *are* here to share knowledge, but in the form of teaching others. If a question is too specific, confusing, subjective, or otherwise bad, we close it. Such questions don't generally teach others.

Please don't look at SO as your personal assistant for every which problem you have.